# std::function expression does not result in a function which accepts 1 Arguement

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, std, std-function

I am learning at using std::function to pass functions. I have taken the code code from MSDN Site which shows me how to get to know if a Process is started.

http://pastebin.com/gVkXZC9b

I know the function void signal_onProcessStart is not necessary I will enlarge it later.

My Problem is that my Compiler is telling me that there is an Error for std::function.

Expression does not result in a function which accepts 1 Arguement.

I am using the German Version of Visual Studio, so I translated it. I think the error is called differently in English.

All Functions which shall be triggered have void as "Return-Value" and HRESULT* as the only parameter.

Greetings

EDIT:

I have made a small example with the same error:

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

class workingClass
{
private:
    std::function<void(int)> f;
public:
    workingClass(std::function<void(int)> p)
    {
        this->f = p;
    }
    void triggerme(int x)
    {
        this->f(x);
    }
    ~workingClass(){}
};

class managingClass
{
private:
    function<void(int)> f;
    workingClass * ptr;
    int x;
protected:
    void trigger(int x)
    {
        this->f(x);
    }
public:

    managingClass(function<void(int)> f)
    {
        this->f = f;
        function<void(int)> tmp = bind(&managingClass::trigger, this->x);
        ptr = new workingClass(tmp);
        ptr->triggerme(20);
    }
    ~managingClass(){}
};

void triggered(int x)
{
    cout << "it is triggered";
}

int main()
{
    function<void(int)> t = bind(&triggered, 20);
    managingClass temp(t);
    system("pause");
}
```

ERROR LINE 1149 in the file functional
Expression will not result in a function which accepts 1

Comment: Can you reduce the wall of code to a [[minimal, but complete test case](http://sscce.org/)], and post that here instead of the pastebin? And please also indicate which line produces the error.

Comment: Look at the Markup EDIT: A small example what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [placeholders](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) for your purpose.
[This](http://ideone.com/IAaRoi) will work:

```
using std::placeholders::_1;

class workingClass
{
private:
    std::function<void(int)> f;
public:
    workingClass(std::function<void(int)> p)
    {
        this->f = p;
    }
    void triggerme(int x)
    {
        this->f(x);
    }
    ~workingClass(){}
};

class managingClass
{
private:
    function<void(int)> f;
    workingClass * ptr;
    int x;
protected:
    void trigger(int x)
    {
        this->f(x);
    }
public:

    managingClass(function<void(int)> f)
    {
        this->f = f;
        function<void(int)> tmp = bind(&managingClass::trigger, this, _1);//, this->x);
                                                                //    ^^
        ptr = new workingClass(tmp);
        ptr->triggerme(20);
    }
    ~managingClass(){}
};

void triggered(int x)
{
    cout << "it is triggered";
}

int main()
{
    function<void(int)> t = bind(&triggered, _1);//, 20);
                                        //   ^^
    managingClass temp(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bind statement is wrong.

Since `trigger` is a member function of `managingClass`, it cannot be stored in a `std::function<void(int)>` directly. It needs to be told on which concrete instance of the class (that is, which object) the function should be invoked.

In other words, you can think of it as a function with the signature `void(managingClass*,int)`:

```
managingClass(function<void(int)> f)
{
    std::function<void(managingClass*,int)> foo =
        std::mem_fn(&managingClass::trigger);
    // don't worry about the std::mem_fn here too much. It's required
    // to keep the compiler happy, since in C++ member function pointers
    // require different handling than ordinary function pointers,
    // but has no deeper meaning
    foo(this, 42);
}
```

What you want to do now is get rid of the `managingClass*` argument (the concrete object) but *leave the second parameter* (the `int`), so the user can decide on its value when invoking the function. This is what [`std::placeholders`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) is used for:

```
managingClass(function<void(int)> f)
{
    std::function<void(int)> foo =
        std::bind(&managingClass::trigger, this, std::placeholders::_1);
    // the bind is smart enough that we don't need the std::mem_fn in here
    foo(42);
    // note how we no longer need to pass the 'this' here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `bind` is incorrect. A bind-expression which doesn't use any placeholders (`_1` and similar) results in a function with *no parameters.* If you have a `void foo(int)`, the type of `bind(&foo, 20)` corresponds to `std::function<void()>`. The `int` parameter is *bound* to 20, it can no longer be set from outside.

That's what `bind` is for - binding some arguments, and optionally leaving others unbound. For example, [this will print `105`](http://ideone.com/FCx5lh):

```
int foo(int x, int y, int z)
{ return x * y + z; }

int main()
{
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  std::function<int(int, int)> b = std::bind(&foo, _1, 10, _2);
  std::cout << b(10, 5) << '\n';
}
```

Additionally, non-static member functions take an object (or pointer to object) as their first argument when bound. So, for example, you can do [this](http://ideone.com/eybWPM):

```
struct Foo
{
  int id;

  int bar(int x) const
  { return 2 * x + id; }
};

int main()
{
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  Foo foo1 = {1};
  Foo foo2 = {2};

  std::function<int(int)> f1 = std::bind(&Foo::bar, foo1, _1);
  std::cout << f1(10) << '\n';  // prints 21
  std::cout << f1(20) << '\n';  // prints 41

  std::function<int(const Foo&)> f2 = std::bind(&Foo::bar, _1, 10);
  std::cout << f2(foo1) << '\n';  // prints 21;
  std::cout << f2(foo2) << '\n';  // prints 22;

  std::function<int()> f3 = std::bind(&Foo::bar, foo1, 40);
  std::cout << f3() << '\n';  // prints 81;
}
```

It's difficult for me to say what exactly you're trying to achieve with your code, but this info should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks alot you and ComicSansMS helped me a lot :)